# ImportError with Geopandas due to Missing libtiff.5.dylib on macOS

Tags: importerror, geopandas

I'm facing an issue with importing Geopandas in my Conda environment (`geodata_env`) on a macOS system. The error message indicates a missing `libtiff.5.dylib` library:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/lf/miniconda3/envs/geodata_env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyproj/_network.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libtiff.5.dylib
```

Upon investigation, I found that `libtiff.5.dylib` is only present in my base Conda directory (`/Users/lf/miniconda3/lib/`) and not in the `geodata_env` directory (`/Users/lf/miniconda3/envs/geodata_env/lib`). However, the `geodata_env` directory contains `libtiff.6.dylib`, along with other related `libtiff` files.

Interestingly, in the base directory, `libtiff.5.dylib` is a symlink pointing to `libtiff.6.dylib`. This suggests that `libtiff.6.dylib` could potentially be backward compatible with `libtiff.5.dylib`.

1. Tried installing `libtiff` version 5 explicitly in the `geodata_env` environment using Conda, but it wasn't available.
2. **Since `libtiff.5.dylib` is a symlink to `libtiff.6.dylib` in the base environment, I considered creating a similar symlink in the `geodata_env`, which allowed me to import Geopandas without an error!**

***Questions:***

- Is creating a symlink from `libtiff.6.dylib` to `libtiff.5.dylib` in my `geodata_env` a viable solution for this issue?
- Are there potential risks or better approaches to resolve this missing library issue for Geopandas on macOS?